# Why bochsdbg failed to load bochsrc.txt but bochs can?

Tags: bochs

I can load bochsrc.txt on bochs, but failed to load bochsrc.txt on bochsdbg.

My bochsrc.txt is

```
  megs: 32
  romimage: file=/usr/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-latest
  vgaromimage: file=/usr/share/bochs/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest
  floppya: 1_44=boot_loader.img, status=inserted
  boot: a
  mouse: enabled=0
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I was missing `-q` parameter on `bochsdbg`.

When I run this, it works!

```
  bochsdbg -q -f bochsrc.txt
```